# Android - setOnClickListener for TextView

Tags: android, onclicklistener

It should be straightforward, but I am not sure where something is wrong.
I try to catch the click on the `TextView` with:

```
public void runNextTask(){
    final View addView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.addnewtracker, null);
    final TrackerInfo newInfo = new TrackerInfo();
    //set up for model selection
    TextView modelTextview = (TextView)addView.findViewById(R.id.modelEdit)

    modelTextview.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });
}
```

Thee XML for the `TextView` is:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/model"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/Tracker_model" 
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="onClick"/>
```

But when I click on the `TextView`, it does not go into the `onClick()` method.
What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: try remove android:onClick="onClick"

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can remove this:

```
android:onClick="onClick"
```

Or, remove this:

```
modelTextview.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {

     }
});
```

and have this:

```
public void onClick(View v)
{
    // do something
}
```

`android:onClick="onClick"/>` // It would be better to rename the method to avoid confusion

Also, you have this:

```
<TextView
     android:id="@+id/model" // id is model
```

so initialize your `TextView` as below:

```
TextView modelTextview = (TextView)addView.findViewById(R.id.model);
```

Answer (score 5):

This line: `android:onClick="onClick"` Tells Android to look in the activity for a method with this signature:

```
public void onClick(View v)
```

This wasn't your intention, as you've set the OnClickListener inside your code and haven't created the dedicated method for it in the activity.
So your options are either to simply remove the `android:onClick="onClick"` from your xml file or remove the on click listener you've created and change it to an onClick method (and preferablly change it's name to something better than onClick...

Answer (score 3):

```
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.other_activity);
 findViewById(R.id.TextView).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }
});
```

Comment: Please explain the solution

Comment: this is a method of implementing onclick listener without a textview variable

Answer (score 1):

**Change :**

```
 TextView modelTextview = (TextView)addView.findViewById(R.id.modelEdit);
```

to

```
 TextView modelTextview = (TextView)addView.findViewById(R.id.model);
```

and there is no need of `android:onClick="onClick"` in your xml code if you want do this with java code

Answer (score 1):

If you change your code to have this structure it will work:

```
public void runNextTask(){
   ...
}

public void onClick(View v) {

}
```

as you're telling in your xml to capture the click for the text view (`android:onClick="onClick"`) in `onClick` module, you don't need to add an onClick listener in your java code.

Answer (score 0):

> for every view component we can call setOnclickLister() like that for
>   TextView also call

```
textview.setOnclickListener(new setOnclickListener
                           {
                                public void onclick()
                                                   {


                                                    }
                           }
                            );``
```

Answer (score 0):

It is beacause of onClick attribute in your layout file. Remove the following line from your layout file,

`android:onClick="onClick"`

The updated TextView will be like this,

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/model"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/Tracker_model" 
    android:clickable="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can also Try this..**

```
 modelTextview.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                   // do something good...
                });
```